# Seperate persistence unit and application into different OSGI bundles in an Equinox environment

Tags: jpa, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipselink, equinox

I have implemented a persistence unit including `META-INF/persistence.xml` in a separate bundle. Now I want to use this bundle in another plugin. However, I am not able to instantiate the `EntityManagerFactory`.

See below for the contents of the relevant files.

**What works**

If I put `META-INF/persistence.xml` into the application bundle than the following returns a valid `EntityManagerFactory`

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = new PersistenceProvider().createEntityManagerFactory("de.viate.muja.dao.jpa", <properties>);
```

**What not works**

The above line yields `null` if `persistence.xml` is only in the persistance bundle.

The EclipseLink documentation refers to [Gemini](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/3.0/solutions/install004.htm#CHDJBFEA) with respect to OSGI. This site proposes the [lookup using the OSGI services](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gemini/JPA/Documentation/JPAServices)

```
context.getServiceReferences(EntityManagerFactory.class.getName(), "(osgi.unit.name=de.viate.muja.dao.jpa)");
```

This doesn't work too.

On the Gemini page there is a class `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder`. No idea where it is defined in OSGI context!?

What can I do to get a valid service reference? Which bundles are necessary in addition to those already imported (see below) and in which Eclipse (2022-03) feature are they included?

Alternatively: is there a way to import `persistence.xml` from the persistence bundle?

**Persistence Bundle - MANIFEST.MG**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.viate.muja.dao.bundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
DynamicImport-Package: *
Export-Package: de.viate.muja.dao;version="1.0.0";uses:="jakarta.persi
 stence,jakarta.persistence.metamodel,org.eclipse.persistence.descript
 ors.changetracking,org.eclipse.persistence.indirection,org.eclipse.pe
 rsistence.internal.descriptors,org.eclipse.persistence.internal.ident
 itymaps,org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving,org.eclipse.persiste
 nce.queries,org.eclipse.persistence.sessions"
Import-Package: jakarta.persistence;resolution:=optional,jakarta.persi
 stence.metamodel;resolution:=optional,java.beans;resolution:=optional
 ,java.lang;resolution:=optional,java.lang.invoke;resolution:=optional
 ,java.util;resolution:=optional,java.util.function;resolution:=option
 al,java.util.stream;resolution:=optional,org.eclipse.persistence.anno
 tations;resolution:=optional,org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.chan
 getracking;resolution:=optional,org.eclipse.persistence.indirection;r
 esolution:=optional,org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors;reso
 lution:=optional,org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps;resolu
 tion:=optional,org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa;resolution:=optio
 nal,org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving;resolution:=optional,org
 .eclipse.persistence.queries;resolution:=optional,org.eclipse.persist
 ence.sessions;resolution:=optional
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=17))"
```

**Persistence Bundle - persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="de.viate.muja.dao.jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <class>[omitted for brevity]</class>

    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>

    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Application Bundle - MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.viate.muja.ui
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.osgi;bundle-version="3.17.200",
 org.osgi.service.jdbc;bundle-version="1.0.1",
 jakarta.persistence-api;bundle-version="3.0.0",
 org.eclipse.persistence.core;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 org.eclipse.persistence.asm;bundle-version="9.1.1",
 org.eclipse.persistence.jpa;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql;bundle-version="3.1.0",
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.mssql-jdbc;bundle-version="10.2.0",
 de.viate.muja.dao.bundle;bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at [Aries JPA](https://aries.apache.org/documentation/modules/jpaproject.html) which implements the [OSGi JPA Service Specification](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/8.0.0/service.jpa.html).

Comment: Is Aries JPA an replacement for EclipseLink or an enabler? Can I use it in an Eclipse Target Platform? If yes what ist the repository URL? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is not helpful to the question because it is unclear how Aries relates to the tags `eclipse-plugin` or `equinox`. Please explain it more elaborately or leave a comment instead. Thank you